# Why divide a variable before type conversion?

Tags: c

I'm looking at the RNG from K&R2 2.7 Type Conversions:

```
unsigned long int next = 1;

/* rand:  return pseudo-random integer on 0..32767 */
int rand(void)
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next / 65536) % 32768;
}

/* srand:  set seed for rand() */
void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

Why is `next` divided by 65536 before it is type cast to `unsigned int`?

My first instinct was it had something to with `int` being 16-bit or `RAND_MAX` being 32767 at the time, but I still get the same results (https://oeis.org/A061364) on my current machine, with `int` at 32-bit and `RAND_MAX` at 2147483647.

And apologies if I'm missing something obvious and apologies to those who think K&R2 is outdated - the example still appears in the C standard, C17 7.22.2.2 The srand function, so I'm assuming my question is still valid nowadays.

Comment: It's just part of the random number generator formula they code to use. Without it, you would have a linear congruential generator, which has poor characteristics.

Comment: @RaymondChen: This *is* a linear congruential generator, just one that only returns the upper bits of the recurrence value and always discards the lower 16 bits that have less entropy.

Comment: @rsarson To see the effect being discussed, try changing the `return` statement to return `next % 32768` or just `next`, and then write a loop printing several consecutive values of `rand() % 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing *before* the cast is necessary when `int` is (or *can be*) 16-bit, and not when `int` is 32-bit.

The whole sequence of dividing by 65536 and taking the remainder by 32768 is a somewhat obfuscated way to extract bits 16 to (exclusive) 31 of `next`. Casting to a 16-bit type as the first step immediately discards the bits that we want, so that's out. Casting to a 32-bit type doesn't do any harm, the bits that we want are still there, doing the division as the second step works in that case.

If there was no division (or right shift) at all, neither before nor after the cast, then the result would be a worse PRNG: effectively that would change it from a "31-bit PRNG with 15-bit output" into a 15-bit PRNG (since the update formula has the property that information only flows "up" through the number, the higher bits never affect the lower bits, any truncation of it can be seen as a PRNG with fewer bits of state, and could be rewritten as such). As is typically for a linear congruential generator, the higher bits are "better", the lower bits have very small periods (the least significant bit is not random at all, it just alternates).

Comment: It's worth noting that for several years after the first port of BSD Unix to 32-bit VAX processors, the performance of `rand()` became terrible, because someone carelessly changed the `return` statement to return all 32 bits, that is, they turned it into a pure LCRG with its attendant periodicity.

Comment: @harold Follow-up question: what is meant by "extended for 32 bits" in https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/rand_r.c?  If I test K&R2 2.7, it repeats after 2^31 iterations.  If test rand_r(), its 2^27.  I also noticed in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use, ANSI C "output bits of seed" is "bits 30..16" compared to glibc "bits 30..0".  And is https://oeis.org/A096553 related, ie, "output limited to 15bit"?

Comment: Also, slightly off-topic, but @steve-summit, I have your 2015 lecture notes for K&R2 :)

Comment: @rsarson "extended for 32 bits" apparently means "use 3 steps of rand to extract 31 random bits and glue them together" (not 32 bits, as you found out). A096553 is the state of the generator instead of its output.

Answer (score 2):

By doing the divide before the cast, the code ensures that the divide is done with the type of `next` (which is `unsigned long` -- at least 32 bits) rather than the type cast to (`unsigned int`), which might be as small as 16 bits.

Note that the cast is not actually needed, just the parens, so

```
return (next / 65536) % 32768;
```

would do the same thing -- it would just do the mod with the 32-bit type, but since this is just masking off the upper bits (returning the bottom 15 bits), it ends up being the same.